# whats the fastest way to find eigenvalues/vectors in python?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Currently im using numpy which does the job. But, as i'm dealing with matrices with several thousands of rows/columns and later this figure will go up to tens of thousands, i was wondering if there was a package in existence that can perform this kind of calculations faster ?

Comment: Does numpy not scale well? I thought it was designed for things like that. Isn't that the whole point of vectorized operations?

Comment: tens of thousands is not a lot and numpy will crush it quickly.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

- **if your matrix is sparse, then instantiate your matrix using a constructor from *scipy.sparse* then use the analogous eigenvector/eigenvalue methods in *spicy.sparse.linalg*. From a performance point of view, this has two advantages:

  - your matrix, built from the spicy.sparse constructor, will be smaller in proportion to how sparse it is.
  - the [eigenvalue/eigenvector methods](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs) for sparse matrices (*eigs*, *eigsh*) accept an optional argument, *k* which is the number of eigenvector/eigenvalue pairs you want returned. Nearly always the number required to account for the >99% of the variance is far less then the number of columns, which you can verify *ex post*; in other words, you can tell method not to calculate and return all of the eigenvectors/eigenvalue pairs--beyond the (usually) small subset required to account for the variance, it's unlikely you need the rest.
- **use the linear algebra library in *SciPy*,** *scipy.linalg*, instead
  of the *NumPy* library of the same name. These two libraries have
  the same name and use the same method names. Yet there's a difference in performance.
  This difference is caused by the fact that *numpy.linalg* is a
  *less* faithful wrapper on the analogous LAPACK routines which
  sacrifice some performance for portability and convenience (i.e.,
  to comply with the *NumPy* design goal that the entire *NumPy* library
  should be built without a Fortran compiler). *linalg*  in *SciPy* on
  the other hand is a much more complete wrapper on LAPACK and which
  uses *f2py*.
- ***select the function appropriate for your use case***; in other words, don't use a function does more than you need. In *scipy.linalg*
  there are several functions to calculate eigenvalues; the
  differences are not large, though by careful choice of the function
  to calculate eigenvalues, you should see a performance boost. For
  instance:

  - *scipy.linalg.eig* returns *both* the eigenvalues and
    eigenvectors
  - *scipy.linalg.eigvals*, returns only the eigenvalues. So if you only need the eigenvalues of a matrix then *do not* use *linalg.eig*, use *linalg.eigvals* instead.
  - if you have a real-valued square symmetric matrices (equal to its transpose) then use *scipy.linalg.eigsh*
- ***optimize your Scipy build*** Preparing your SciPy build environement
  is done largely in SciPy's *setup.py* script. Perhaps the
  most significant option performance-wise is identifying any optimized
  LAPACK libraries such as *[ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/)* or Accelerate/vecLib framework (OS X
  only?) so that SciPy can detect them and build against them.
  Depending on the rig you have at the moment, optimizing your SciPy
  build then re-installing can give you a substantial performance
  increase. Additional notes from the SciPy core team are [here](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/BuildingGeneral).

Will these functions work for large matrices?

I should think so. These are industrial strength matrix decomposition methods, and which are just thin wrappers over the analogous Fortran ***LAPACK*** routines.

I have used most of the methods in the linalg library to decompose matrices in which the number of columns is usually between about 5 and 50, and in which the number of rows usually exceeds 500,000. Neither the *SVD* nor the *eigenvalue* methods seem to have any problem handling matrices of this size.

Using the *SciPy* library *linalg* you can calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues, with a single call, using any of several methods from this library, ***eig***, ***eigvalsh***, and ***eigh***.

```
>>> import numpy as NP
>>> from scipy import linalg as LA

>>> A = NP.random.randint(0, 10, 25).reshape(5, 5)
>>> A
    array([[9, 5, 4, 3, 7],
           [3, 3, 2, 9, 7],
           [6, 5, 3, 4, 0],
           [7, 3, 5, 5, 5],
           [2, 5, 4, 7, 8]])

>>> e_vals, e_vecs = LA.eig(A)
```

Comment: On my machine, numpy's eigvals is actually faster than scipy's.

Comment: I am using scipy.sparse.linalg.eign.eigsh on 40,000 by 40,000 symmetric sparse matrix. It takes me nearly 30 mins to find 125 smallest eigenvectors. So I am also wondering what the most efficient eigenvector solver is in Python.

Comment: Is MKL, which comes by default in Anaconda these days, as fast as it's going to get in terms of linalg optimization? https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/

Answer (score 9):

If your matrices are sparse, you can try using scipy's sparse eigenvalue function, which should be faster:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html

You might also check out specialized packages like SLEPc, which has python bindings and can do calculations in parallel using mpi:

http://code.google.com/p/slepc4py/