# Whats the fastest way to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 2D real symetrical Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue

Is there a faster way to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 2D real symetrical Matrix besides:

```
N = 10101
S = np.random.random((N,N))
S = (S + S.T)/2

eigenValues, eigenVectors = np.linalg.eig(S)
idx = eigenValues.argsort()[::-1]

eigenValues = eigenValues[idx]
eigenVectors = eigenVectors[:,idx]
```

This take too long for me

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468054/the-fastest-way-to-calculate-eigenvalues-of-large-matrices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`np.linalg.eigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) since it's designed for real symmetric matrices and it will use a special algorithm. Another benefit is that the returned eigenvalues are sorted in ascending order, so you will not need to use `argsort()`.

Speed comparison with `N = 1010` so I'm not waiting around forever:

```
eig_vals, eig_vects = np.linalg.eig(S)
# 628 ms ± 45.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

eig_vals, eig_vects = np.linalg.eigh(S)
# 89.1 ms ± 2.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

from scipy import linalg as la
eig_vals, eig_vects = la.eigh(S)
# 346 ms ± 10.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`np.linalg.eigh` is the fastest by far.