# Intel MKL speeds up numpy.dot, but why doesn't it speed up scipy.linalg.eig?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, scipy

I want to find a fast way to do eigen-decomposition using Numpy/Scipy. I found this post [whats the fastest way to find eigenvalues/vectors in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684238/whats-the-fastest-way-to-find-eigenvalues-vectors-in-python/6688540#6688540) and followed the advices to rebuild Numpy/Scipy with Intel MKL (in an newly created Python virtual environment).

Then I had a simple performance test on both the old virtual environment with ordinarily built Numpy/Scipy, and the new virtual environment with MKL-built Numpy/Scipy. Specifically I tested numpy.dot and scipy.linalg.eig, hoping the MKL version will be faster.

The results show that MKL-built Numpy is faster than normal Numpy, while MKL-built Scipy is slower than normal Scipy:

```
Numpy: two (3000 * 3000) matrix dot product

MKL:1s / Normal: 2s

Scipy: eigen-decompose (1000 * 1000) matrix

MKL 1.5s / Normal: 1.5s
```

Why doesn't MKL speed up Scipy? Is there any other way to speed up Scipy's eigen-decomposition?

Comment: Good question! Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @eleanora Sorry, nope.